# How to get access to the data in a CMS

Tags: cms, content-management

I plan to build a website where landlords can manage their properties. The website will collect data about each property and then do useful things with that data -- produce reports, email alerts etc.

Most of the website is just going to be collecting data and then a small part will be querying that data. **So I want to use a CMS to collect the data, but then access that data so I can query it.** I am a SQL Server developer so the easiest for me would be to access the tables and query it with SQL. And then create stored procedures that the website could use to get reports etc.

But I want to work within the functionality of a CMS, rather than hack it and use it in a way that it not designed of (and then I cannot get upgrades!).

I am aware that accessing the tables directly might be the wrong solution. Maybe I need to access the data via some API. Or move the data to another database where I can query it there.

I really just want to be able to build the data collection pages via a CMS, but still give myself access to the data.

**I am not asking for a recommendation for a CMS, but rather how I can work with a CMS and also access the data.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *"I am aware that accessing the tables directly might be the wrong solution. Maybe I need to access the data via some API. "* - it seems you already know the answer, so I doubt we can tell you really something new.

Answer (score 2):

> The website will collect data do useful things with that data -- produce reports, email alerts etc.

Using a CMS for all of that makes the CMS the single point of failure. When a component is heavy loaded the other components get slow although it can be fixed through scaling it might be cumbersome to scale just the heavy loaded component, instead use the CMS to support reports users, both the designers and the audience, and have a separate component for collecting data, both text and media. In CMSes literature this type of setup is referred to be headless CMS.

Of course this approach is appropriate when the traffic to support is mostly high.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on the CMS, but I would venture to say that *most* support access via API (over HTTP) and that you should not mess with the database directly.

A CMS can work for this task, though the GUI will likely be overly generic and you will need to be careful when selecting and configuring one so that landlords do not get access to each others' data.

Comment: Ahh, yes! I would need a Multi-Tenant CMS. Thanks @Jacob Raihle.

Answer (score 1):

Most CMSs store their data in a relational database, so you can use SQL to access it.
However, the tricky part will probably be how to configure the CMS to do what you want it to do while storing the data in a way that enables you to process it further. This highly depends on the specific CMS that you choose, there's no generally valid answer.

Many CMSs support some kind of extension/plugin mechanism, but this means quite a bit of learning and coding (often PHP).

Since some CMSs come in free/open versions, you can try them out pretty easily without wasting a lot of money. You need to invest your time, though.